# Jetbrains Rider slow debug startup compared to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: rider

Im currently working on a monolothic ASP NET MVC 5, .Net 4.6.1 web app and i have problem with the debug startup time in JetBrains Rider. When using Visual studio 2017  it takes around 60 seconds for the entire web app to start but with Rider it takes atleast 3 minutes. I havent changed the default debug settings.

Comment: You might report to JetBrains as a bug. I don't think posting it here can help much.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: I just re-opened a bug with this, it was never solved. It feels like Rider is getting more and more sluggish in general without a single place I could pinpoint.